# Loading ProgressSpinner for ListRowPresenter

Tags: android, android-tv

When I look at other apps and even Google's native leanback launcher (this is for Android TV specifically), I notice that they create a header, but rather than adding content to `ListRowPresenter` object, they get a ProgressSpinner, which then populates with content after the (usually network) thread(s) complete. Is there a way to set up an indeterminate progress type thing? I've been looking for examples and other projects that may have included it, but have hit a dead-end.

Comment: Is the LoadingCardView introduced in [Vineyard](https://github.com/hitherejoe/Vineyard) project satisfies your requirement?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) set to indeterminate mode to put it in a spinner-like visual.

Comment: Right. That is what I'm looking for. However, there appears to be a way to make it apart of the `ListRowPresenter`, which is what I'm trying to do. In my project... the first row, is pulled from a database, so no progress spinner needed. However, the next two rows are both pulled from web services. While those rows are being pulled, I'd like to see a progress bar with indeterminate progress there for the row layout.

Comment: It's just a view.  You can show them conditionally as part of your view hierarchy just like any other view and switch visibility between them and other views.